# XML not inserting into mysql properly

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm trying to get the contents of an XML file into tables in my  database using php.

This is pretty much the gist of the XML file.

```
<Meet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.nspace.co.za/">
  <Name>Test Meet 1</Name>
  <StartDate xsi:nil="true" />
  <EndDate xsi:nil="true" />
  <MeetId>168</MeetId>
  <CustomerId>37</CustomerId>
  <DatabaseId>3</DatabaseId>
  <EventList>
    <Event>
      <CustomerId>37</CustomerId>
      <DatabaseId>3</DatabaseId>
      <EventId>1111</EventId>
      <Name>Formation Skydiving 2-Way - Open 168</Name>
      <EventTeamList>
        <EventTeam>
          <CustomerId>37</CustomerId>
          <DatabaseId>3</DatabaseId>
          <EventTeamId>00bab00</EventTeamId>
          <Name>201 - Test Team 2</Name>
          <NationAbbreviation />
          <Position>1</Position>
          <TotalScore>51.00</TotalScore>
        </EventTeam>
        <EventTeam>
          <CustomerId>37</CustomerId>
          <DatabaseId>3</DatabaseId>
          <EventTeamId>0001</EventTeamId>
          <Name>202 - Test Team 9</Name>
          <Position>2</Position>
          <TotalScore>41.00</TotalScore>
        </EventTeam>
        <EventTeam>
          <CustomerId>37</CustomerId>
          <DatabaseId>3</DatabaseId>
          <EventTeamId>0001</EventTeamId>
          <Name>204 - Test Team 7</Name>
          <Position>2</Position>
          <TotalScore>31.00</TotalScore>
        </EventTeam>
      </EventTeamList>
    </Event>
  </EventList>
</Meet>
```

And here's my PHP:

```
$mdstring = file_get_contents('detail' . $meet->MeetId . '.xml');
$meetdetails = new SimpleXMLElement($mdstring);

if($mdstring){

    foreach($meetdetails->EventList->Event as $event)
    {
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO events (event_id, meet_id, event_name)
        VALUES ('{$event->EventId}', '{$meet->MeetId}', '{$event->Name}')");

                foreach($event->EventTeamList->EventTeam as $eventTeam)
                {
                    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO event_teams (team_id, event_id, meet_id, team_name)
                    VALUES ('{$eventTeam->EventTeamId}', '{$event->EventId}', '{$meet->MeetId}', '{$eventTeam->Name}')");
                }

    }
}
```

Almost everything inserts fine, with the exception of contents of the tag EventTeamId, for some reason it is just starting the `team_id` column from `0` and auto incrementing.  I can't for the life of me figure out why, the other data I'm inserting in the same manner, `$eventTeam->Name`,  works perfectly fine.

Any Ideas?
Thank You.

Comment: Enable error_reporting, and do some proper debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`team_id` is primary key of your table `event_teams`, and seems it's type is integer, and it's `auto-increment` as well

`auto-increment` column means that it's value automatically create by incrementing last biggest inserted value, although you can set your custom value for this field but remember that this column's type is `INTEGER` and you can only set integer value.
since `team_id` column are primary key of your table then you can not have two row with same value in it

finally in your `XML` file `EventTeamId`s are not integer

Comment: Oh,  Ignore that '00bab00',  that isn't the value I was actually using.  Sorry, but now I guess I understand that 0000 is not an Int.  I really should have spotted that I was just throwing random numbers in for testing purposes.  Thank You.